# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) в QuerySelectField flask

Tags: python, sql, веб-программирование, flask, wtforms

Мне нужно вывести список доступных концернов автомобилей из базы данных(sqlalchemy). Прочитал что вместо обычного selectfield можно использовать queryselectfield, который автоматически делает заброс к базе данных и это очень удобно. Но почему-то после того как я поменял selectfield на queryselectfield стала появляться ошибка: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`
Код формы:

```
class AddCarForm(FlaskForm):
    model = StringField('Model', validators=[DataRequired()])
    concern = QuerySelectField(u'Concern', query_factory=lambda: Concern.query, \
        allow_blank=False)

    price_per_day = FloatField('Price per day', validators=[DataRequired()])

    pic = FileField('Load Picture', validators=[DataRequired()])

    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

Шаблон:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <form action="{{ url_for('add_car') }}" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}

        <p>
            {{ form.concern }}
        </p> 

        <p>
            {{ form.model.label }}
            {{ form.model(size=16) }}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{ form.price_per_day.label }}
            {{ form.price_per_day(size=10) }}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{ form.pic.label }}
            {{ form.pic }}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{ form.submit }}
        </p>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

И представление(оно пока ничего не делает, т.к. не могу решить предыдущую проблему, но всё же):

```
@app.route('/cars/add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_car():
    form = AddCarForm()
    return render_template('add_car.html', form=form)
```

Как можно это исправить? Какие именно значения нужно распаковать? Просто я не вижу здесь вообще функций, которые бы могли возвращать кортеж или список, множество и т.д., которые могут вернуть более двух значений. Помогите пожалуйста исправить эту проблему. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914900/flask-wtforms-alchemy-queryselectfield-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-ex